# A Logical Mistake on OOP

Tags: php, oop, yii

I'm learning Yii Framework . I'm working with a framework first time, i need some advices. 
I have a getSocials() function on my Controller .

```
private function getSocials($id)
    {
        $socials=Socials::model()->find("socials_user=$id");
        foreach ($socials as $social)
        {
            $type = $social["socials_type"];
            $allSocial .= "<li><a href=\"#\" rel=\"nofollow\">$type</a></li>";
        }
        return $allSocial;
    }
```

(it's private because i'm calling it from another function only).
I'll explain it line by line,

```
$socials=Socials::model()->find("socials_user=$id");
```

Getting datas from database which socials_user collumn equals to **$id**, via *Socials* model.

```
foreach ($socials as $social)
```

$socials returning as an array because there are a few lines which socials_user collumn equals to **$id** on database .

```
$allSocial .= "<li><a href=\"#\" rel=\"nofollow\">$type</a></li>";
```

On foreach loop, adding `<li>...</li>` to end of string, so **$allSocial** will be `<li>...</li><li>...</li>...`

BUt i'm getting **Undefined variable: allSocial** error . When i remove *dot* from front of *equal symbol* (*=*),  it's working. But this time on foreach loop, it's overwriting always and finally **$allSocial** containing only last `<li>...</li>`

Are there any logical mistake ?

Comment: Those solutions posted by other guys are ok, but I strongly reccomend not to create html elements inside a controller. As long as Yii is an MVC framework you should put visual information only insde Views an not inside Controller.

Comment: @ArtoAle, thank you, can you give an example please ?

Comment: yes, sure: intead of creating the `<ul>` and `<li>` elements inside your controller class, you should instead pass the $social variable throught your view. Eg: if you have a `actionDisplaySocial()` method, you'll probably have a call to the `render()` method too. When you call this method, you pass as parameter a map of object, and you should pass the $socials array there. so, you'll use `$this->render('my_view_file', array("socialInfo"=>$socials));`. This make available inside your viewfile (`my_view_file` in the example) a `$socialInfo` variable that contain the same array. Have a look at

Comment: [Yii CController::render()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#render-detail) for more info.

Comment: Moreover, if you need this block of html generated in many pages, you should consider making a widget instead of iterating in each pages. [Yii Widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view#widget)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$allSocial` is not defined anywhere, you cant attach a string to an undefined variable. Try it like this:

```php
private function getSocials($id)
{
    $socials=Socials::model()->find("socials_user=$id");
    $allSocial = '';
    foreach ($socials as $social)
    {
        $type = $social["socials_type"];
        $allSocial .= "<li><a href=\"#\" rel=\"nofollow\">$type</a></li>";
    }
    return $allSocial;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `$allSocial` before you try to concatenate anything to it. You may also want to consider returning an array instead so you can easily access the different strings.

> ```
> private function getSocials($id) {
>     $socials=Socials::model()->find("socials_user=$id");
>     $allSocial = array();
>     foreach ($socials as $social)
>     {
>         $type = $social["socials_type"];
>         $str = "<li><a href=\"#\" rel=\"nofollow\">$type</a></li>";
>         array_push($allSocial, $str);
>     }
>     return $allSocial; 
> }
> ```

Comment: I don't see why you would want to create another array, it looks like this function is for outputting purposes. Creating an array of all the HTML strings would require you to `foreach` over them again at outputting.

Comment: I don't know if he's suggesting creating another array, but typically you would pass an array to a view if it has presentation code it in. For a small fragment like this, you could argue it isn't a big deal, but since the OP said he was just learning Yii, a common mistake is to put too much into the controller.

Comment: Yes, you would pass an array to a view, but you would not pass an array of HTML strings. You would pass an array with the `$social` objects/arrays, so you would just pass `$socials`.

Answer (score 1):

find function will return only one record which is not an array so foreach will never execute 
replace the code with following to get it working right :

```
private function getSocials($id)
{
    $socials=Socials::model()->findAll('socials_user=:socials_user', 
                    array(':socials_user'=>1));
    $allSocial = '';
    foreach ($socials as $social)
    {
        $type = $social["socials_type"];
        $allSocial .= "<li><a href=\"#\" rel=\"nofollow\">$type</a></li>";
    }
    return $allSocial;
}
```

Comment: thank you ! This is my other question's (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404102/reading-multiply-rows-from-database-on-yii-framework) answer :) Please, can you write this answer to that question, so i can vote it :)