# Reading Multiply Rows From Database On Yii Framework

Tags: php, oop, yii

I think database operations isn't explained very well, on guide .  I couldn't understand it. Because of this i have a question. I asked it Yii Forums but there isn't any answer. This is my socials table for example.

```
+------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| socials_ID | socials_link              | socials_type | socials_user | socials_order |
+------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
|         48 | link                      |            8 |            1 |             4 |
|         47 | blablabla                 |           11 |            1 |             3 |
|        301 | userlinkuse               |            9 |            1 |             6 |
+------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
```

I want to get all datas from this table which socials_user collumn equals to 1 . There can be a few rows (in this example there are 3 rows) .

What method should i use ? I'm trying this :

```
                $allSocial = '';
                $socials=Socials::model()->findByAttributes(array('socials_user'=>1));
                foreach ($socials as $social)
                {
                        $type = $social["socials_type"];
                        $allSocial .= $type . ",";
                }
                return $allSocial;
```

but this is returning 4 , l , 8 ,1 , 4 . (First letter / number of every collumn on first row)

How can i use it ? findByAttributes AR is adding `LIMIT 1;` to SQL ?

Comment: *[A model represents a single data object](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.model)*

Comment: @hakre, so how can i list datas which socials_user collumn equals to 1, for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this method to get records from the table having socials_user column value equal to 1.

```
$socials=Socials::model()->findAll('socials_user=:socials_user', array(':socials_user'=>1));
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using a Model from YII. Models always represent one Object in YII. That's why it looks like that there is a `LIMIT 1` as you described it.

You need to query the database instead to return a set of rows. Here is some YII database access example code to give a picture how that works ([from here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#fetching-query-results)):

```
$dataReader=$command->query();
// calling read() repeatedly until it returns false
while(($row=$dataReader->read())!==false) { ... }
// using foreach to traverse through every row of data
foreach($dataReader as $row) { ... }
// retrieving all rows at once in a single array
$rows=$dataReader->readAll();
```

I do not know if you already have a database connection set up, but I assume so as you're already using a database. So this is what you need to access the DB Command object then to actually call `query()` ([from here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#executing-sql-statements)):

```
$connection=Yii::app()->db;   // assuming you have configured a "db" connection
// If not, you may explicitly create a connection:
// $connection=new CDbConnection($dsn,$username,$password);
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
// if needed, the SQL statement may be updated as follows:
// $command->text=$newSQL;
```

Hopefully this information if of use to you.

Comment: thank you hakre, can you adapt this to my example please? So, i can understand it very well.

Comment: Check Varun Mittal's answer instead. I think that's easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

better yet, use findAllByAttributes.

your code should be:

```
$socials=Socials::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('socials_user'=>1));
```

Doc : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAllByAttributes-detail